# How can I swap a parent pointer and a child pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, polymorphism, instanceof

`Weapon` inherits from `Item`.

`weapon` is a member of class `Hero`. I want to swap it with the `item` passed in the function, which is also a `Weapon` for this example (I'll add more cases).

```
void Hero::equip(Item* item){
    
    if(instanceof<Weapon>(item)){std::swap (item, static_cast<Item>(weapon));}
}
```

Basically, when something is equipped from the hero's inventory, I want it to get stored in the corresponding member of the `Hero`, and the `item` that was previously equipped to get stored back in the inventory, no matter the type of item. The inventory is a `std::vector<Item*>` so it can hold polymorphic items.

Upcasting `weapon` doesn't seem to be working, because `Item` is virtual. Every other type of casting I tried also failed, and so did some attempts to manually swap them. If you're wondering about `instanceof`, I copied this template so I can use it in C++:

```
template<typename Base, typename T> 
inline bool instanceof(const T *ptr) {
    return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(ptr) != nullptr;
}
```

When I use `Item*` instead of `Item`, I get:

> no matching function for call to 'swap(Item*&, Item*)'

Comment: Hint: You dont' want to swap `Item`s, you want to swap `Item*`s

Comment: Also, when dealing with polymorphism, the cast you're looking for is `dynamic_cast`

Comment: Why are you using swap instead of replacing?  What is `weapon`'s exact declaration?

Comment: When I use Item* instead of Item I get ' no matching function for call to 'swap(Item*&, Item*)'

Comment: Also how do you highlight words like that? sorry I'm new

Comment: I want to swap them and not just replace because the item that just got unequipped goes back to the hero's inventory.

Comment: You probably should come up with a more complete [mre], as your current code appears to have several deficiencies. (For example, swapping with a parameter of type `Item*` will not affect the inventory, but a `Item*&` might.) Preferably, show the code that gives the error message since that *might* be on the right track.

Comment: @GeorgeT You might be interested in reading [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), in particular the "Code Spans" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::swap()` takes non-const lvalue references as input, which is why you are getting a "no matching function" error when you try to swap with `static_cast<Item*>(weapon)`, which is not returning an lvalue that you can swap with.

In order to assign the new `item` to the `weapon` member, you need the `Weapon*` pointer that `dynamic_cast` returns, so your `instanceof()` template is not helping you here.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void Hero::equip(Item* &item) {
    if (Weapon *new_weapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(item)) {
        Item *old_weapon = weapon;
        weapon = new_weapon;
        item = old_weapon;
    }
}
```

Or:

```cpp
void Hero::equip(Item* &item) {
    if (Weapon *w = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(item)) {
        std::swap(weapon, w);
        item = w;
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using C++14 or later, you can use [`std::exchange()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) instead:

```cpp
void Hero::equip(Item* &item) {
    if (Weapon *new_weapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(item)) {
        item = std::exchange(weapon, new_weapon);
    }
}
```

Note: the use of `Item*&` for the `item` parameter assumes that `equip()` is being called with an `Item*` pointer taken *directly* from an `inventory` element, eg:

```cpp
hero.equip(hero.inventory[index]);
```

And not *indirectly*, like this:

```cpp
Item *item = hero.inventory[index];
hero.inventory.erase(hero.inventory.begin()+index);
hero.equip(item);
```

If the `item` being passed in to `equip()` is not a *direct* reference to an element of the `inventory`, then I would suggest having `equip()` return the old `Item*` and let the caller decide what to do with it, eg:

```cpp
Item* Hero::equip(Item* item) {
    if (Weapon *new_weapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(item)) {
        Item *old_weapon = weapon;
        weapon = new_weapon;
        return old_weapon;
    }
    ...
    return nullptr;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
Item* Hero::equip(Item* item) {
    if (Weapon *w = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(item)) {
        std::swap(weapon, w);
        return w;
    }
    ...
    return nullptr;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
Item* Hero::equip(Item* item) {
    if (Weapon *new_weapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(item)) {
        return std::exchange(weapon, new_weapon);
    }
    ...
    return nullptr;
}
```

And then the caller can do something like this:

```cpp
Item *item = hero.inventory[index];
hero.inventory.erase(hero.inventory.begin()+index);
item = hero.equip(item);
if (item) hero.inventory.push_back(item);
```

Comment: @MooingDuck [that won't work](https://ideone.com/JqNUv0): "*no matching function for call to ‘swap(Item*&, Weapon*&)’*". The inputs to `std::swap()` have to be the same type, so one of them will have to be casted in this case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks once again! It was a bit to take in but i got it all now. Equiping can only be done from the inventory so I'll use your first example.

Comment: @MooingDuck nope, [that won't work, either](https://ideone.com/dNeJln): "*no matching function for call to ‘swap<Item*>(Item*&, Weapon*&)’*". `std::swap()` takes its parameters by reference. You can pass a `Weapon*` to an `Item*`, and a `Weapon&` to an `Item&`, but you can't pass a `Weapon*&` to an `Item*&`